# How can I combine/concatenate elements of an array based on bits of an int?

Tags: c#

I would like to concatenate strings (from an array) based on an input int value.

For example:

```
int Input = 3;
string[] Items = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
// output = "A, B"

// example 2: input = 8
// output = "D"
```

The first element of the array (0) should be associated with the least significant bit of the input value. Values in the array are concatenated with a string such as "," or "+".

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: With a `StringBuilder` and a bit-shift, I suppose.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? I'd suggest you try it first, and come back with what you've got.

Comment: Do you have to use an array? Why not use an enumeration decorated with a flag attribute which has enum names of A, B, C...?

Comment: @Ken I started with a String.Join and LINQ but I wasn't sure how to do any bitwise operations with LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want to treat your input value as a bitmask?

This should work:

```
int Input = 3;
string[] Items = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};

var bitMask = new BitArray(new[]{Input});
return Items.Where((c,i)=>bitMask.Get(i)).ToArray();
```

Basically what I'm doing is converting your number into a BitArray, which will allow me to easily tell what bits are set and not set in your number. I'm then using a little Linq to filter the Items array by index, based on whether the corresponding index of the BitArray is set.

Understand that this will only work if the array has less than sizeof(int)*8 (32) elements. Beyond that, the BitArray won't have indexes to Get() unless you specify additional integer values that can be chained together in the int[] array passed to the BitArray constructor.

Comment: Nice use of lambda expression

Comment: This looks like what I was wanting to do with LINQ. `BitArray` is the missing piece I didn't know about.

Comment: The actual application for this is to glue SQL statements together for various "OR" conditions. In my case there are five statements and thus 32 possible combinations (30 really, since I invalidate 0 and 31). Thanks for the extra qualifying statements.

Comment: As a followup note for myself (and anyone learning LINQ); I was unfamiliar with using two arguments with a `Where` method (I had only used them with `Aggregate` previously). The second argument represents the index of the element within the array/collection. [*MSDN for more info*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx)

Comment: @JYelton: Yes. This overload of Where, and other Linq extension methods that are overloaded like this, allow you to reference items by an "index". However, caveat emptor; because Linq works with IEnumerables, the "index" number is just an autoincremented value produced by the code behind the extension method, and has no innate relationship with the indices (if any) of the source collection. You can thus use it to, for instance, select every fifth item from a collection; you CANNOT use it to find items at particular indexes of the original collection, after having already filtered or ordered.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
int input = 3;
for(int i=0; i<items.Length && input != 0; i++) {
    if((input & 1) == 1) {
        if(sb.Length > 0) sb.Append(',');
        sb.Append(items[i]);
    }
    input >>= 1;
}
```

Comment: Some parenthesis are missing: `if((input & 1) == 1)`

Comment: This works too though inserting the glue between elements is a bit easier with a `String.Join("+", Array.Where())` syntax, for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the least significant bit of an integer using arithmetic modulo 2.

```
3 % 2 => 1
4 % 2 => 0
```

Once you've determined the least significant bit of an integer, you can discard the least significant bit by doing integer division by 2.

```
3 / 2 => 1
4 / 2 => 2
```

After discarding the least significant bit, you can use the modulus operator again to get the new least significant bit. Wrap this in a loop and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If the array isn't absolutely necessary you could use an enumeration:

```
[Flags]
enum Items
{
    A = 1,
    B = 2,
    C = 4,
    D = 8
}
```

Then use:

```
string GetItems(int items)
{
    string[] itemList = new string[4];
    int currPos = 0;

    foreach (Items item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Items)))
    {
        if ((items & (int)item) == (int)item)
        {
            itemList[currPos] = item.ToString();
            currPos++;
        }
    }

    return String.Join(",", itemList, 0, currPos);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea except the actual strings are lengthy SQL conditionals. I simplified the question for the sake of highlighting the concept, but this answer would totally work if that weren't the case.